# How to subscribe to changes in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, stream, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I don't know how to subscribe to changes in DynamoDB database. Let me show an example: User A sends a message (which is saved in the database) to User B and in the User B's app the message automatically appears.

I know this is possible with recently released AWS AppSync, but I couldn't integrate it with Ionic (which I am using). However, there must be an alternative since AWS AppSync was released only at the end of 2017/beginning of 2018.

I've also seen something called Streams in DynamoDB but not sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) is designed specifically for capturing/subscribing to table activity. You can set up a Lambda Function with your notification logic to process the stream and send notifications accordingly.