# Subscribing to changes in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, aws-appsync

I have made an app in React Native, that posts to an AppSync graphql end point some data.

Using a RaspberryPi I would like to subscribe to changes that get made to the underlying DynamoDB.

I have access to the AWS ecosystem and I'm comfortable in JS and Python.

My question is what is the best way to subscribe to DynamoDB changes in the RapberryPi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subscribe to changes in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495112/how-to-subscribe-to-changes-in-dynamodb)

Comment: DynamoDB Streams -> Lambda -> expose an endpoint on your Pi for this to hit

Comment: @JamesWhiteley You can't do what you are suggesting "DynamoDB Streams -> Lambda -> expose an endpoint on your Pi for this to hit". You would end up with DynamoDB triggering one Lambda invocation, and API Gateway triggering a different Lambda invocation. There would be no way to get the DynamoDB data over to the Lambda invocation serving the API Gateway request.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is what is the best way to subscribe to
>   DynamoDB changes in the RapberryPi?

As already commented, good start would be using the [Dynamo DB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) - I'd suggest to bind a lambda 
function to the stream.  In theory there are other ways to process the update stream (kinesis,..), but for the start the lambda may be a good choice for your case. With the lambda you may store the messages to a service, where your device could pick it up.

The second part is - how do you get the updates to your raspberry pi. I'd suggest using the SQS (you can use [long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-sqs-long-polling.html) ) or IoT topic (with mqtt).

Comment: I'm having a look at SQS and IoT (mqtT) now. It's that implementation I'm unsure about.

Comment: @Adam The main idea is that your device could pull (read) messages intended for the device.  I am not sure if you can make a durable subscription with an IoT topic (so you could receive messages occurred while disconnected). That may be decisive factor between IoT and SQS service